# Generate The Auto Incrementig Number With Prefix Laravel

Tags: laravel-5.7

I have table named as product.The product table Consistis of the productcode field
and while adding the product I need to generte the code as PRO-1,PRO-2,PRO-3 in the sequence for the product code field and its must be loaded in the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have Created the function in my product model and succefully done this

```
public static function generateSeriesNumberWithPrefix($tableName = '', $autogenField = '', $autogenStart = '', $autogenPrefix = '')
    {
        $listFiledValues = DB::table($tableName)->select($autogenField)->get();
        if ($listFiledValues->isEmpty())
        {
            $generatedAutogen = $autogenPrefix.$autogenStart;
            return $generatedAutogen;
        }
        elseif ($listFiledValues->isNotEmpty())
        {
            foreach($listFiledValues as $listFiledValue)
            {
                $eachListarray = $listFiledValue->$autogenField;
                $totalListArrays[] = $eachListarray;
            }
            foreach($totalListArrays as $totalListArray)
            {
                $stringRemovedEachListArray = substr($totalListArray,strlen($autogenPrefix));
                $stringRemovedTotalListArray[] = $stringRemovedEachListArray;
            }
            $maximumValue = max($stringRemovedTotalListArray);
            $generatedAutogen = $autogenPrefix.++$maximumValue;
            return $generatedAutogen;
        }
    }
```

And Finally in the create function

```
public function create ()
    {
    $autogen = Product::generateSeriesNumberWithPrefix('product','autogen','1','PRO-');
    return view('product.formadd', compact('result','sequence'));           
    }
```

I am using the Laravel Form builder So that

```
{!! Form::text('productcode', $autogen, null, ['class' => 'form-group']) !!}
```

here `generateSeriesNumberWithPrefix` is a function name and `Product is a Model Name`

Main Advantage of this function is it does not depend upon other fields such as `created_at`or the Max value in the `primary key`it is standalone function